# Subclassed fragment onCreateView

Tags: java, android, inheritance, android-fragments

for the sake of not duplicating the code I've decided in my program to create a `BaseFragment` (which extends `Fragment`) to hold for some boilerplate data and provide proper handling of pause/resume, as well as the `newInstance(String myPram)` method. Long story short: The role of the BaseFragment is to ensure the saving and restoring of the state, i.e. restoring myPramas a local variable...

What I wanted to do next was to extend that `BaseFragment` in order to handle two different types of layout for two different Fragments (each of the needs the handling of the MyParam filed): `EditFragment` and `DetailFragment`.
The problem arises now, because no View is inflated for the Fragment, though they are added as a transaction (so they are transparent!).
`EditFragment` and `DetailFragment` both provide the `onCreateView()` method, in order to build their own views, I am they are correct since I managed to create them without the "subclassing mechanism", and of course BaseFragment does not provide an implementation of the `onCreateView()` but no result, they draw no UI.

I tried putting some super.onCreateView() here and there, with no result as well...What am I doing wrong?
Here's the base Fragment:

```
public class TimetableBaseFragment extends Fragment {

public static String ID_FIELD = "id";
public static String ID_DESC = "desc";
private String id;
private String desc;

// Constructor to deliver previous position along with itself
public static Fragment newInstance(String id, String desc) {
    TimetableBaseFragment f = new TimetableBaseFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ID_FIELD, id);
    args.putString(ID_DESC, desc);
    f.setArguments(args);
    return f;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle args = getArguments();
    if (args != null) {
        id = args.getString(ID_FIELD);
        desc = args.getString(ID_DESC);
    }

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        id = savedInstanceState.getString(ID_FIELD);
        desc = savedInstanceState.getString(ID_DESC);
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString(ID_FIELD, id);
    outState.putString(ID_DESC, desc);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        id = savedInstanceState.getString(ID_FIELD);
        desc = savedInstanceState.getString(ID_DESC);
    }
}

public String getExamId() {
    return id;
}

public String getExamDesc() {
    return desc;
}
}
```

And the one I am trying to add is:

```
public class TimetableEditFragment extends TimetableBaseFragment {

private LinearLayout mLlEditEmpty;

private ArrayList<ScheduleUser> lessons;
private TimetableEditRecyclerViewAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    lessons = new ArrayList<>();
    mAdapter = new TimetableEditRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity());
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_timetable_edit, container, false);

    mLlEditEmpty = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.LOGIC_empty);
    RecyclerView mRvEdit = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.HEADER_rv);
    mRvEdit.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRvEdit.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    mRvEdit.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL_LIST));
    mRvEdit.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    Toolbar examDesc = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.HEADER_examDesc);
    examDesc.setTitle("TOOLBAR Testing");


    FloatingActionButton add_fab = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.EDIT_fab);
    add_fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addLesson(new ScheduleUser());
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

public void addLesson(ScheduleUser newItem) {
    lessons.add(newItem);
    mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(lessons.size() - 1);
}

public class TimetableEditRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TimetableEditRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    /* Lots of stuff */
}
}
```

PS: I've noticed that it's very likely that the child onCreateView() **does not get called at all**, since I had an error, which was due to be fund at runtime, but the system did not notify.

Please help!

Comment: How do you instantiate TimetableEditFragment? If you're calling newInstance() on the parent class, than it will give you a TimetableBaseFragment - static methods don't get overridden by subclasses in Java.

Comment: Try to comment out everything inside your `onCreateView` and see if runs.

Comment: @Egor thanks, you're right. I solved it moving newInstance() inside each of the Fragments, keeping the duplication of code at an acceptable level anyway! It looks like I'm missing some fundamentals! Ouch! :)

Comment: @fiipi, Glad I could help!